# PHP app\console wont work trying to create bundle for Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, console, bundle

I have installed Symfony2 on a Xampp server with PHP 5.3.8 and everything works ok ( the php, the symfony demo page ).

I try to create my own helloWorld, as the tutorial says :

> php app/console generate:bundle --namespace=Acme/HelloBundle --format=yml

I go Start->Run->CMD and put that line of code and it gives me back this :

> could not open input file : app/console

I put the PHP directory to the System PATH but the problem persists.

Comment: its working for me Next i created a new bundle as per symfony doc. php app/console generate:bundle --namespace=Acme/TestBundle But how to access the page (url)
http:// localhost /newsf/web/app_dev.php/test/John

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To execute command you should move to root directory of your project in terminal/CMD.

Please note that in `version 2.5` some changes has been made so command will not work with `app/console`

**Note:** From 2.5 `app/console` is replaced by `bin/console`.

Please check [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-3.0.md) for changes. Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23994473/631652) for more details about difference.

Answer (score 5):

Most probably, you're not in the symfony2 project directory.

1. start the windows console as you're doing it (Start->Run->CMD)
2. then move to the symfony2 project root directory with the command cd:
   "cd c:\htdocs\path\to\your\symfony2\project"
3. then run the command from the tutorial

the thing is that the part of the command from the tutorial "app/console" means the path to the "console" script in the "app" directory of the symfony2 project.