# What is the new Symfony 3 directory structure?

Tags: symfony

I just created a new Symfony 2.5 project with a regular composer command:

```
php composer.phar create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition path/ 2.5.0
```

The Terminal asks me:

> Would you like to use Symfony 3 directory structure?

What is this *Symfony 3 directory structure?* I have never seen it before... Is it new since 2.5?

What are the benefits to using it?

Is there any way to replicate this directory structure?

Comment: Note that in the meantime, this question has been removed from the installer because it was causing a certain degree of confusion among the users. More info: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/issues/674

Comment: @Corneliu it has indeed. However, it is still possible to trigger the question, by setting an environment variable before running Composer. See this question and answer that I posted: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24956881/1001110

Answer (score 176, accepted):

### I want to use the new Symfony 3 directory structure, but I don't see the question?

The question `Would you like to use Symfony 3 directory structure?` has been removed when creating a new project due to the confusion it caused. You can force the use of the directory structure using the following:

If you prefer the new structure, you can add the environment variable `SENSIOLABS_ENABLE_NEW_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE` to your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` like so:

#### Make all future projects ask for the new structure

```
# .bash_profile
# ALL new composer installs will ask `Would you like to use the new Symfony3 strucure?`
export SENSIOLABS_ENABLE_NEW_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE=true
```

#### Make ONLY THIS project ask if we want to use the new structure.

If you wanted it for a particular project only (a one off), you can use:

```
SENSIOLABS_ENABLE_NEW_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE=true composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition path/ "2.5.*"
```

If the environment variable `SENSIOLABS_ENABLE_NEW_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE` is set and set to `true`, `composer` will ask if you want to use the new directory structure.

Continue reading below for all the changes between the `Symfony2` and `Symfony3` directory structure.

---

## What is the new Symfony 3 directory structure?

*(and how does it effect me & my workflow)*

I looked into this by creating 2 projects, one with `symfony-2.5.0` directory structure, one with `symfony-3` (directory structure change only).

Make one of each project:

```
# say `N` to `Would you like to use Symfony 3 directory structure?`
$ composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition symfony-2.5.0/ 2.5.0

# say `Y` to `Would you like to use Symfony 3 directory structure?`
$ composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition symfony-3/ 2.5.0
```

So now we have the 2 different directories we want to compare.

---

## Find the `diff`erence

You can `diff` between the 2 directories using:

```
$ diff -rq symfony-2.5.0/ symfony-3/
/** (Returned from the diff)
Files symfony-2.5.0/.gitignore and symfony-3/.gitignore differ
Files symfony-2.5.0/.travis.yml and symfony-3/.travis.yml differ
Only in symfony-2.5.0/app: bootstrap.php.cache
Only in symfony-2.5.0/app: cache
Only in symfony-2.5.0/app: console
Only in symfony-2.5.0/app: logs
Only in symfony-2.5.0/app: phpunit.xml.dist
Only in symfony-3/bin: console
Only in symfony-3/bin: symfony_requirements
Files symfony-2.5.0/composer.json and symfony-3/composer.json differ
Only in symfony-3/: phpunit.xml.dist
Only in symfony-3/: var
Files symfony-2.5.0/vendor/autoload.php and symfony-3/vendor/autoload.php differ
Files symfony-2.5.0/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php and symfony-3/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php differ
Files symfony-2.5.0/web/app.php and symfony-3/web/app.php differ
Files symfony-2.5.0/web/app_dev.php and symfony-3/web/app_dev.php differ
*/
```

This shows the files that differ in the 2 versions.

---

## Breakdown of `diff`

Here's a breakdown of everything in the diff.

```
# These files still exist in both versions (with different content)
.gitignore
.travis.yml
composer.json
vendor/autoload.php
vendor/composer/autoload_real.php
web/app.php
web/app_dev.php

# The following files have been removed from 2.5.0
# {RemovedFile2.5}      |  {ReplacedWith3.0}
app/cache               |  var/cache
app/logs                |  var/log
app/bootstrap.php.cache |  var/bootstrap.php.cache
app/console             |  bin/console
app/phpunit.xml.dist    |  phpunit.xml.dist

# The following files are new in 3.0
bin/symfony_requirements # run via CLI
```

---

## Benefits of the Symfony 3 directory structure

The new directory structure has a number of benefits, all of which are minor and may require minimal changes to your workflow.

### PHPUnit

`phpunit` can be run from the project root without having to explicitly specify the path of the configuration file.

```
# Symfony2
phpunit -c app/phpunit.xml

# Symfony3 (no need to specify the configuration file location)
phpunit
```

### Binary Executables

All binary executable files are now all located in a single location - the `bin` directory *(similar to a unix-like os)*.

```
# you can update your `PATH` to include the `bin` directory
PATH="./bin:$PATH"

# From your project root you can now run executables like so:
console
symfony_requirements
doctrine

# else with no `PATH` update
bin/console
bin/symfony_requirements
bin/doctrine
```

### The new `/var` directory

The new `/var` directory contains the files to which the system writes data to during the course of its operation *(similar to a unix-like os)*.

This also makes it easier to add permissions, the entire `/var` directory should be writable by your webserver. You can follow the [Symfony2 guide for setting permissions](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html#book-installation-permissions) (substituting `app/cache` && `app/logs` with `var`), any other files you want to write locally could also be located here.

```
# default symfony3 `var` directory
var/bootstrap.php.cache
var/cache
var/logs
```

### Symfony requirements check

Running `symfony_requirements` will output mandatory & optional environment configurations.
e.g:

```
********************************
* 'Symfony requirements check' *
********************************

* Configuration file used by PHP: /usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini

/** ATTENTION **
*  The PHP CLI can use a different php.ini file
*  than the one used with your web server.
*  To be on the safe side, please also launch the requirements check
*  from your web server using the web/config.php script.
*/

** Mandatory requirements **
'
 OK       PHP version must be at least 5.3.3 (5.5.11 installed)
 OK       PHP version must not be 5.3.16 as Symfony wont work properly with it
 OK       Vendor libraries must be installed
 OK       var/cache/ directory must be writable
 OK       var/logs/ directory must be writable
 OK       date.timezone setting must be set
 OK       Configured default timezone "Europe/London" must be supported by your installation of PHP
 OK       json_encode() must be available
 OK       session_start() must be available
 OK       ctype_alpha() must be available
 OK       token_get_all() must be available
 OK       simplexml_import_dom() must be available
 OK       APC version must be at least 3.1.13 when using PHP 5.4
 OK       detect_unicode must be disabled in php.ini
 OK       xdebug.show_exception_trace must be disabled in php.ini
 OK       xdebug.scream must be disabled in php.ini
 OK       PCRE extension must be available
'
** Optional recommendations **
'
 OK       xdebug.max_nesting_level should be above 100 in php.ini
 OK       Requirements file should be up-to-date
 OK       You should use at least PHP 5.3.4 due to PHP bug #52083 in earlier versions
 OK       When using annotations you should have at least PHP 5.3.8 due to PHP bug #55156
 OK       You should not use PHP 5.4.0 due to the PHP bug #61453
 OK       When using the logout handler from the Symfony Security Component, you should have at least PHP 5.4.11 due to PHP bug #63379 (as a workaround, you can also set invalidate_session to false in the security logout handler configuration)
 OK       You should use PHP 5.3.18+ or PHP 5.4.8+ to always get nice error messages for fatal errors in the development environment due to PHP bug #61767/#60909
 OK       PCRE extension should be at least version 8.0 (8.34 installed)
 OK       PHP-XML module should be installed
 OK       mb_strlen() should be available
 OK       iconv() should be available
 OK       utf8_decode() should be available
 OK       posix_isatty() should be available
 OK       intl extension should be available
 OK       intl extension should be correctly configured
 OK       intl ICU version should be at least 4+
 OK       a PHP accelerator should be installed
 OK       short_open_tag should be disabled in php.ini
 OK       magic_quotes_gpc should be disabled in php.ini
 OK       register_globals should be disabled in php.ini
 OK       session.auto_start should be disabled in php.ini
 OK       PDO should be installed
 OK       PDO should have some drivers installed (currently available: mysql, sqlite, dblib, pgsql)
'
```

---

## Conclusion

Looks like a good tidy up by Sensio Labs, all the above changes make perfect sense, they should be easy to implement when upgrading from `2.5` to `3.x`, these will probably be the least of your problems!

### Read the docs

[Symfony 2.x => 3.0 Upgrade docs here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150905153321/https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-3.0.md)
[Symfony 3.0 The Architecture](https://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_architecture.html)

### Release Date for Symfony 3

It looks far off looking at the Release process *(worth a read)*:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/community/releases.html

[image: Updated Symfony release Process]
<sub>(source: [symfony.com](https://symfony.com/doc/current/_images/release-process.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your help, yes I hope that migrating from 2.* to 3.0 will be possible and easy.

Comment: Now I think that why command not working because composer moved from app to bin.

Comment: As of yesterday, we've removed the "3.0" directory structure question because it was confusing people and there's no real benefit yet to using this structure. 3.0 is still a long time away, but when we get there, there will certainly be details on how to upgrade :).

Comment: @weaverryan Is there a way to override it (except manually)? I like the new structure better and we already have a few projects running with it.

Comment: @MarcelBurkhard I've updated my answer to show how to force the new directory structure, you simply add the environment variable `SENSIOLABS_ENABLE_NEW_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE=true` (view the top of my answer for full details)

Comment: You should update the answer and note that they removed this option from the installer.

Comment: I find this new `symfony-bin-dir` little [confusing](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioDistributionBundle/issues/235).

Comment: @Anil also you forget to say diff into Position of unitTest Class for Bundle.

in `Symfony 2.x` : test directory was into Bundle Directory under src Folder.
in `Symfony 3.x` : test directory out Bundle Directory under src Folder, now under root of Project

Comment: I took the liberty to add the [official documentation link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_architecture.html) to the answer because - well it's official. :)

Answer (score 38):

Here is a list of changes between the old and new directory structure:

- A new `var` folder is introduced
- `app/console` is moved to `bin/console`
- `app/check.php` is moved/renamed to `bin/symfony_requirements`
- `app/phpunit.xml.dist` is moved to the root folder
- `app/SymfonyRequirements.php` is moved to `var/SymfonyRequirements.php`
- the `app/cache` and `app/logs` folders have been moved to `var/cache` and `var/logs`, respectively

(Currently not all of the old files seem to be removed, so you might want to do so manually before committing all files into version control. See [this issue](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioDistributionBundle/issues/141))

### So what's the benefit?

There are a couple of benefits with these changes. First of all, all files and folders that should be writable for Symfony are now in the `var` folder. This should make configuring permissions a lot easier: simply assure write access to the `var` folder and you're done.
This is suggested in [this blog post](http://christianriesen.com/post/88202545774/symfony-2-5-using-a-new-structure) - I haven't tried this myself, yet.

Secondly, all executables, including `console`, are now in the `bin` folder. That allows Bash users for instance to add this to their `.profile` file:

```
# set PATH so it includes current bin folder
PATH="./bin:$PATH"
```

Now you don't even have to type `bin/console` anymore, simply `console` will suffice (note that I had to reboot in order for this to work).

There are some other improvements as well. `app/check.php` is now an executable, so you can call it using `bin/symfony_requirements` instead of `php app/check.php`. (Using the `.profile` trick I described earlier, simply `symfony_requirements` will suffice as well)

And, last but not least, you no longer have to specify the location of the configuration file when running PHPUnit. So instead of `phpunit -c app` you can simply execute `phpunit`.

### Can I upgrade existing projects to this new structure as well?

By default, you'll only get the 'Do you want to use the new directory structure' question when creating a new project (using `composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition path/ "2.5.*"`).

However, it is possible to upgrade an existing Symfony application, but it's a somewhat hacky solution. I have managed to do so with a number of applications now, and you can read the steps [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/nicwortel/0c938aa77c5bd4fde064). However, since it wasn't designed for this, I can not guarantee it will allways work.

### Update

It turns out that Symfony no longer asks you if you want to use the new directory structure, when creating a new Symfony application through Composer. However, it is still possible to create Symfony projects with the new directory structure, by using an environment variable. For more information, see [How can I create a new Symfony project with the new directory structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24956881/1001110)

Comment: You don't need to reboot after changing your `.profile`, you can just re-source the file in your current shell, or quit and start a new shell. Running `. ~/.profile` will re-source the file (note the leading dot-space).