# How can I create a new Symfony project with the new directory structure?

Tags: symfony

Until some days ago, it was possible to create a new Symfony project with the [new (Symfony 3) directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23993295/1001110). When running `composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition path/ "2.5.*"`, Composer would ask the following question:

> Would you like to use Symfony 3 directory structure? [y/N]

The new structure offered some improvements, such as `console` being moved from the `app` directory to the `bin` directory, and `phpunit.xml.dist` being moved from the `app` directory to the root directory. The cache and logs directories were moved to a new `var` directory.

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24310405/1001110) (written by me) for a full list of changes.

However, a fresh install of the standard distribution no longer offers this option. It seems like the question [has been removed on July 16th](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioDistributionBundle/pull/146), because the new directory structure created too much confusion, especially for new users. See [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/issues/674) as well.

Is it still possible to create a project using the new directory structure?

Comment: Update: as Symfony 3 is now released, the easiest way to get the new directory structure is to simply create a new Symfony 3 project ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is still possible to trigger the question, and convert a project to the new directory structure. (but only if you are creating a new project, i.e. running `composer create-project`)

To do so, you need to set the `SENSIOLABS_ENABLE_NEW_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE` environment variable to `true`. This can be done by prepending `SENSIOLABS_ENABLE_NEW_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE=true` to the Composer command.

So in order to create a new project, run the following command in your terminal:

```
SENSIOLABS_ENABLE_NEW_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE=true composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition path/ "2.5.*"
```

and Composer will ask you if you want the new directory structure.

### Update

As noted by barius in the comments, this feature has been removed from the Symfony Standard Edition per version 2.7.5. If you really want to use the Symfony 3 structure, you can get it by installing Symfony in 2 steps:

1. Create a new Symfony project with a version constraint so you get the 2.6 version, which still asks you whether you want to use the new directory structure.
2. Then change the version constraint for the `symfony/symfony` package so you'll still get the latest version.

So, execute the following commands from the command line:

```
SENSIOLABS_ENABLE_NEW_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE=true composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition project-directory/ "2.6.*"
cd project-directory
composer require symfony/symfony ^2.7
```

Note: I don't actually recommend this, as this is [not the official recommended way to create a new Symfony project](https://symfony.com/download). So unless you really know what you're doing, just use the Symfony Installer to create new projects.

Comment: This does not work anymore, see https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/commit/02f6add5a954198ec092e803764cc16c37ed2594

Comment: @barius Why not? Why did they change this? I liked to have the new directory structure...

Answer (score 6):

to create the new symfony3 directory structure in symfony2 (>=2.5) you have to do the following:

open your shell/command prompt and run the follwoing command to set a temporary [environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable):

linux:

```
export SENSIOLABS_ENABLE_NEW_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE=true
```

windows:

```
set SENSIOLABS_ENABLE_NEW_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE=true
```

### version 2.5 and 2.6

the question, for creating the new symfony3 directory structure, is asked out of the box after setting the environment variable

### version 2.7 and 2.8

to create the new directory structure from any 2.7 and 2.8 version, the following steps are necessary:

install the 2.7 and up version you want (tested with 2.7 and 2.8), which currently installs 2.7.7

```
composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition myproject "2.7.*"
```

then edit the `composer.json` and add a `update-directory-structure`:

composer.json:

```
--- snip ---
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ],
    "update-directory-structure": [
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::defineDirectoryStructure"
    ]
},
--- snip ---
```

after that just run

```
composer run-script update-directory-structure
```

answer with 'y' and you are done:

```
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::defineDirectoryStructure
Would you like to use Symfony 3 directory structure? [y/N]
```

the `console` file, which is now located in `bin/console` has to be adapted:

change

```
$loader = require __DIR__.'/autoload.php';
```

to

```
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../app/autoload.php';
```

then add the following methods to the `AppKernel` class, in the file `app/appKernel.php`:

```
public function getRootDir()
{
    return __DIR__;
}

public function getCacheDir()
{
    return dirname(__DIR__).'/var/cache/'.$this->getEnvironment();
}

public function getLogDir()
{
    return dirname(__DIR__).'/var/logs';
}
```

update: [knp university article about migrating to the new directory stucture](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony3-upgrade/new-dir-structure)

credits:
  [@davil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22592/davil)

Answer (score 4):

[Symfony3 BETA1](http://symfony.com/blog/symfony-3-0-0-beta1-released) version is Released now,

So you can use [composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md) directly to install new symfony3 version.

Follow [Installing Composer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/composer.html) first if you don't have it already installed.

Then open terminal and type following command:

```
composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition symfony3 "v3.0.0-BETA1"
```

Note: here `symfony3` is name of project or directory which will be created, you can change that.

**Update:**
Symfony 3.0 is stable and current version so one can directly install it as stated in [Official guide](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#creating-a-symfony-application-with-composer).  Follow it for latest version installation.

`composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition my_project_name`

You may like to check these links,

[What is the new Symfony 3 directory structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23993295/what-is-the-new-symfony-3-directory-structure?lq=1)

[Are your favorite bundle ready for #Symfony3?](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GOxJ2lNpLxN12YyZ87Bhsxb0iLAQ7e4UDZbJSly8Sy8/edit?pli=1#gid=0) posted by [@FecaBouffe](https://twitter.com/FecaBouffe)