# I cannot clear the cache (because the cache is outdated)

Tags: symfony, caching

Trying to deploy my updated Symfony2 application, I ran into the following problem.

(note that my application uses [the new Symfony 3 directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23993295/1001110). replace `bin/console` with `app/console` and `var/cache` with `app/cache` if you're using the current directory structure)

I have recently renamed one of my service classes (`VariantSlugListener`). When deploying the application on the staging server, I got the following error when running `bin/console assetic:dump --env=prod`:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MyBundle\Listener\VariantSlugListener' not
>   found in
>   /var/www/example.com/staging/var/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainer.php
>   on line 494

Line 494 of `appProdProjectContainer.php` contains the following code:

```
return $this->services['3f288d4f09c9906944ba7e17358f669b942397baf9d79d5ff0737bb756df7023_1'] = new \MyBundle\Listener\VariantSlugListener();
```

It is no surprise that `\MyBundle\Listener\VariantSlugListener` can not be found, since it has been renamed to `\MyBundle\EventListener\VariantSlugSubscriber` with the latest update. The solution would be to simply clear Symfony's cache.

However, when trying to clear the cache (using `bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`) I get the exact same error as with the `assetic:dump` command. So I get an error because my Symfony cache is outdated, but I can not clear the cache because of the error.

I can probably get around this by manually deleting the contents of the `var/cache` directory, but that doesn't feel like the best solution.

Am I missing something?

Comment: the prod environment is not designed to change php filenames, so sduo rm -rf var/cache*

Comment: Hey John, I forgot to mention. I made the changes on my local development machine and then deployed them to the server using git. Is Symfony's cache not able to handle this?

Comment: maybe you forgot to add var/cache to .gitignore ? personally i would prefer to let your deployment script remove the contents of var/cache after deployment

Comment: @johnSmith maybe that is a good idea. I just thought that `cache:clear` would suffice. It also feels a bit cleaner than removing the cache directory's contents.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are triggering some events that are handled in your VariantSlugListener when doing 'cache:clear'. So your only choice is to just remove contents of the cache directory or to replace the value manually and then run `cache:clear` to warm up the cache.

Comment: The `VariantSlugListener` class was a Doctrine event listener that was being triggered on the `prePersist` event. So it shouldn't be called during the `cache:clear` command...?

Comment: @Nic You'll have to debug it with xdebug. Just go the line of where container tries to instantiate new VariantSlugListener and set a breakpoint. Run the script and by the stack trace you'll able to get a grasp of who is calling it...