# What is the logic behind the changes in directory structure of Symfony2 --> Symfony3?

Tags: logic, symfony

I'm still learning my way around Symfony2 and wondered if anyone could explain the logic behind the changes to the directory structure in Symfony3? It would be interesting to hear the justification for the changes and would hopefully give some clarify on the 'magic' of inheritance/overwriting classes.

Below are the standard directory structures for both versions of Symfony:

## Symfony 2:

```
blog/
├─ app/
│ ├─ console
│ ├─ cache/
│ ├─ config/
│ ├─ logs/
│ └─ Resources/
├─ src/
│ └─ AppBundle/
├─ vendor/
└─ web/
```

## Symfony 3:

```
blog-symfony3/
├─ app/
│ ├─ config/
│ └─ Resources/
├─ bin/
│ └─ console
├─ src/
├─ var/
│ ├─ cache/
│ └─ logs/
├─ vendor/
└─ web/
```

Comment: This question has an excellent answer outlining the differences and their benefits: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23993295/what-is-the-new-symfony-3-directory-structure

Comment: I'd guess the justification is that logs, console and cache aren't something that you create or change by hand, so they don't belong mixed into your app folder.  Cache and log files would be expected to grow over time, so var makes sense.  I'm not exactly sure what console contains, but I'd bet it's binary data, so bin would make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented, [this has already been outlined in my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23993295/what-is-the-new-symfony-3-directory-structure).

A google search for **`symfony 3 directory structure`** also returns it as the first result *(at the time of writing)*.

---

**Here is a quick summary:**

1. The `cache`, `logs` and `bootstrap.php.cache` have been moved to the
   `/var` directory in the root of the project. This makes it easier to
   handle permissions, you should make the entire `var` directory
   writable. (*similar to a unix like OS*). You could also write your own application specific files here.
2. All binary executables (`console`, `symfony_requirements`, `doctrine`) are all now located within the `bin` directory (*similar to a unix like OS*), you can also add your own executables here.
   *Tip:* Update your `PATH` environment variable with the following to automatically include all files in the `bin` directory (in the current working directory) in your path. `PATH="./bin:$PATH"`
3. `phpunit` can now be run from the project root without specifying the configuration file via the `-c` switch.
   `<3.0` - `phpunit -c app/phpunit.xml`
   `>3.0` - `phpunit`

---

You can read a more detailed answer here:

[What is the new Symfony 3 directory structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23993295/what-is-the-new-symfony-3-directory-structure)

Comment: Thanks for answering Anil - I'd followed the link to your answer from @Kaivosukeltaja comment...no further questions!