# New Symfony 3 installation: Could not open input file: app/console in composer install

Tags: php, composer-php, symfony

I installed a fresh symfony3-instance via the official symfony-installer (http://symfony.com/download). After doing the first things, I commited the project to Git and cloned it the other day on another computer. 
After the cloning I ran "composer install" to install all the symfony-dependencies.
Now comes the problem: The script `ScriptHandler::clearCache` stops with an error: `Could not open input file: app/console`.
Thats right - symfony3 has a new directory-structure - so the `console` resides now in `/bin` - not in `/app`.
How can I tell composer/the project to use the new structure instead of the old one?

I read here ([What is the new Symfony 3 directory structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23993295/what-is-the-new-symfony-3-directory-structure)) about the console-command `SENSIOLABS_ENABLE_NEW_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE=true` - but that doesn't work in my case.

Any tips?

Comment: Did the problem only occurred once you cloned the project? Can you compare a fresh Symfony3 and the cloned project?

Comment: I think you may have changed the composer.json file after your initial install.    If bin/console is not found then you need to start over.  Even if clearing the cache helped.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `ScriptHandler` take the dir from the extra config key in the `composer.json` files names as `symfony-bin-dir`. So check that the composer contain the correct configuration key, as example:

<kbd>composer.json</kbd>

```
....
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
    "symfony-var-dir": "var",
    ....
```

EDIT:

The problem was related to the cache of composer. It was solved clearing it with the command:

```
>php composer.phar clear-cache
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @cklm possibly a problem related to the composer cache? Try removing the composer cache via the command `php composer.phar clear-cache`

Comment: thanks a lot - clearing the composer-cache (why?!) solved my problem!

Answer (score 51):

Just create `var` directory. After that `composer install` and `composer update` will work ok.

**Explanation:**

`vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Composer/ScriptHandler.php:462`

```
protected static function useNewDirectoryStructure(array $options)
{
    return isset($options['symfony-var-dir']) && is_dir($options['symfony-var-dir']);
}
```

So you need both to have `symfony-var-dir` in `composer.json`'s `extra` and have this directory existing.

Comment: I can confirm: when `var` is missing => cannot open app/console in composer install. Creating the `var` did the trick for me.

Comment: Did the trick for me too. Experienced this after updating from 3.3 to 3.4 but I have no idea why, never happened before...

Answer (score 9):

I have been running into the same problem.  The script uses the existance of the var directory to decide whether to use the new directory structure or the old one.  If var exists, the new directory structure is used.  Otherwise it uses the old structure.

The default .gitignore file prevents both the var directory and the bin directory from being added to git.

What I did to solve the problem for me was to edit .gitignore in the project directory so that it looks like this:

```
/app/config/parameters.yml
/bin/*
/build/
/composer.phar
/vendor/
/web/bundles/
/var/*
!var/cache
/var/cache/*
!var/cache/.gitkeep
!var/logs
/var/logs/*
!var/logs/.gitkeep
!var/sessions
/var/sessions/*
!var/sessions/.gitkeep
!bin/console
!bin/symfony_requirements
/phpunit.xml
```

I do not pretend to be an expert on .gitignore, so I'm not sure that is the most elegant way of doing it, but it is what worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem:

```
[RuntimeException]
An error occurred when executing the ""cache:clear --no-warmup"" command:

Could not open input file: app/console
```

My console file is in /bin/ folder too so I had to call this from root of project to clear the cache each time I clone the project from DevOps:

```
php bin/console cache:clear
```

Afterwards I can run `composer install` and it works fine