# Composer fails executing app/console cache:clear on symfony 3

Tags: composer-php, symfony

I cant run `composer install` because it fails when executing the `post-install-cmd`-scripts.

The reason is Symfony 3 moved the console app from the app folder to a bin folder.

I have tried `composer clear-cache` and `composer self-update`, so I can verify that I'm running the latest version of composer without any luck... Can anyone help me?

Results from `composer diagnose`

```
composer diagnose
Checking composer.json: FAIL
Defining autoload.psr-4 with an empty namespace prefix is a bad idea for performance
require.symfony/symfony : unbound version constraints (dev-master) should be avoided
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking https connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking github.com rate limit: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking composer version: OK
```

Edit:
Added my composer.json file: [Pastie](http://pastie.org/10638893)

Extra's part:

```
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
    "symfony-var-dir": "var",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
    "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    }
}
```

Error from Composer:

```
Could not open input file: app/console
Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception



  [RuntimeException]                                                         
  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:  
  Could not open input file: app/console                                     
  .
```

Manuall test of `bin/composer cache:clear`:

```
bin/console cache:clear

 // Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug true


 [OK] Cache for the "dev" environment (debug=true) was successfully cleared.
```

The problem repo: https://bitbucket.org/Richardh87/messenger

Comment: what is the exact error?

Comment: did you check that the console.php file still exist inside app/ directory?

Comment: yeah, not `console.php`, just `console`

Comment: Ah sorry, try sudo rm -rf  vendor/* , sudo rm -rf composer.lock then run composer install again

Comment: Alright! That actually worked :D Thank you :) (I also ran `composer clearcache` just to make sure :)  If you post the answer I'll accept it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [new symfony3-installation: Could not open input file: app/console in composer install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34198591/new-symfony3-installation-could-not-open-input-file-app-console-in-composer-in)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Had the same problem. Found that `var` directory was missing.

Adding `var` directory to project root dir solved this for me. It looks like symfony 3 tries to use old project structure if var folder is missing. Hope this can help someone.

Comment: Thanks, I did have the `var` folder in root... My solution have been to symlink `./app/console -> ./bin/console` :)

Comment: Hmm, I noticed I have removed `var` from some projects, so this did solve the problem then! Thank you :)

Comment: @Richard87, glad to know that :)

Comment: This sorted it for me. I was running `composer install` before symlinking shared files (like the `var/` directory and `parameters.yml` in my deploy script. Symlinking these files before the `composer install` fixed the issue.

Comment: In my case I had `var/*` in my gitignore. I replaced it with `var/cache/*`, `var/logs/*`, etc and it worked.

Answer (score 9):

try

```
sudo rm -rf vendor/* 

sudo rm -rf composer.lock
```

then run

```
composer install
```

again

Comment: and a fresh git clone of the project failed misrably, `rm -Rf vendor composer.lock`, `composer clearcache`, `sudo composer clearcache` have no effect anymore :(

Comment: same as always, just `app/console` does not exist... Also, it works when I'm running it in my regular project, but when pushed and cloned to a new folder, it stops working (same composer binary and user)... its really weird

Comment: did you try correctly set permissions in your new folder/project?

Comment: cd to your project folder and try this ..sudo chown -R root:www-data app/cache
sudo chown -R root:www-data app/logs
sudo chown -R root:www-data app/config/parameters.yml

Comment: sudo chmod -R 775 app/cache
sudo chmod -R 775 app/logs
sudo chmod -R 775 app/config/parameters.yml

Comment: I appreciate the help, but it's not a problem with the rights... I'm saving the files and running composer install, all with the same user...

Comment: @Richard87 , I have similar problem. As it turned out, my project missed `var` directory inside the project. If it's absent composer runs `app/console`, otherwise `bin/console`. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Check  the extra config key in the `composer.json` files names as `symfony-bin-dir`.

So check that the composer contain the correct configuration key, as example:

<kbd>composer.json</kbd>

```
....
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
    "symfony-var-dir": "var",
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the gitignore worked for me, like this:

```
# Cache and logs (Symfony3)
/var/cache/*
/var/logs/*
!var/cache/.gitkeep
!var/logs/.gitkeep

# Parameters
/app/config/parameters.yml
/app/config/parameters.ini

# Managed by Composer
/app/bootstrap.php.cache
/var/bootstrap.php.cache
/bin/*
!bin/console
!bin/symfony_requirements
/vendor/

# Assets and user uploads
/web/bundles/
/web/uploads/

# Assets managed by Bower
/web/assets/vendor/

# PHPUnit
/app/phpunit.xml
/phpunit.xml

# Build data
/build/

# Composer PHAR
/composer.phar
```