# Symfony 3 app/console not found

Tags: console, dependencies, composer-php, symfony

I use for  the first time `Symfony` 3, I wanted to install the assets so I run :

```
php app/console assets:install --symlimk
```

And I get the error:

> Could not open input file: app/console

I added it to my composer.json and updated composer but same problem. any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New Symfony 3 installation: Could not open input file: app/console in composer install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34198591/new-symfony-3-installation-could-not-open-input-file-app-console-in-composer-i)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Symfony 3.0, the directory structure was changed. So now you have to use `bin/console` instead of `app/console`.

Comment: ah ok, I see it. Thank you

Comment: I get error in Symfony 3: Could not open input file: bin/console

Comment: Did you just update an old application without changing the directory structure of your project?