# Could not open file app/console Symfony 2.8

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I am using Symfony 2.8 using Symfony 3 directory structure. After recent composer install it is complaining that

```
 An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command: Could not open input file: app/console
```

I looked at the change log and could not find anything regarding this change is there anyway to fix this issue.

Comment: console is now in the bin directory in Symfony 3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New Symfony 3 installation: Could not open input file: app/console in composer install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34198591/new-symfony-3-installation-could-not-open-input-file-app-console-in-composer-i)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a `console` folder inside the `app` one ?

btw try to do `php bin/console cache:clear --no-warmup`

`bin/console` is the new directory in Symfony 3. It's maybe the same issue.

Comment: I am aware that console is in bin directory now. That's why I have this entry in composer.json


    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },

But somehow Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache is still looking for app/console.

Comment: Maybe this can help you, this is a similar issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34198591/new-symfony-3-installation-could-not-open-input-file-app-console-in-composer-i

Comment: That was it you have to have var directory in there. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Create `var` directory.

**Explanation:**

*vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Composer/ScriptHandler.php:462*

```
protected static function useNewDirectoryStructure(array $options)
{
    return isset($options['symfony-var-dir']) && is_dir($options['symfony-var-dir']);
}
```

So you need both to have `symfony-var-dir` in `composer.json`'s `extra` and have this directory existing.

Comment: And add a file like .gitkeep, such that yout VCS will pick the new folder up.